# Root explorer Android 11 (API 30)

Tags: android, root, android-11

When I target api 30 and try to retrieve the list of files in the path "/data/data" (with root permissions), I only get the folder of my app, while with api 29 or lower I get all the files present.

How can I retrieve all files even with api 30?

Code used:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.topjohnwu.superuser.Shell

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val result = Shell.su("ls -la /data/data").exec()
        Log.e("files", result.out.toString())
    }
}
```

I used this library for root: https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu

Answer (score 1):

These are the new limitations added in Android 11:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

> #### Document access restrictions
>
> To give developers time for testing, the following changes related > to the Storage Access Framework (SAF) take effect
> only if your app targets Android 11 or higher.
>
> **Access to directories**
>
> You can no longer use the
> [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory)
> intent action to request access to the following directories:
>
> - The root directory of the internal storage volume.
> - The root directory of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card
>   is emulated or removable. A reliable volume is one that an app can
>   successfully access most of the time.
> - The Download directory.
>
> **Access to files**
>
> You can no longer use the
> [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory)
> or the
> [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file)
> intent action to request that the user select individual files from
> the following directories:
>
> - The `Android/data/` directory and all subdirectories.
> - The `Android/obb/` directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: Ok, but how to bypass it?